# How to remove the annoying Reconnect to Face messages from Win8?

Tags: windows-8

In Win 8 it seems that it is assumed that everyone is a facebook user. For a multitude of reasons I avoid facebook but win8 is constantly prompting me to reconnect to facebook, both under People and Messaging. Is there a way to delete these connections or attempts at connections?

Comment: This is not default behavior.  Have you uninstalled the application asking for your login information?  Windows 8 doesn't even have a Facebook Windows 8 application.

Comment: It's actually asking as part of the default "Messaging" app.

Comment: Update your question to clarify that fact.